# sequence whose series is convergent, but square is not convergent

Tags: math, analysis

What is a sequence (b<sub>n</sub>) such that the series

∑ b<sub>n</sub>

is convergent and the series

∑ b<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>

is divergent?

I know the example for other way round but I'm stuck with this one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not programming-related.

Comment: Hint: Use [math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com) but read [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) first!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se], not programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

a_n = (-1)^n / sqrt(n)

([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447353/convergence-of-a-series-implies-the-convergence-of-the-squares)) For positive a_n there is no such sequence.

Next time, you might want to ask at math.SE.